# Copy Multiple Files w/ Same Extension but Add Date

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I want to create a single command that will backup all my `*.db` files in a directory but I want to append the current date.

`a.db` -> `a_2016-04-21.db`

`b.db` -> `b_2016-04-21.db`

`c.db` -> `c_2016-04-21.db`

I know there is the:

```
cp a{.db,_`date +%F`.db}
```

command, but I am unsure of how to create a single command that can copy all of my `*.db` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function with a loop in your ~/.bashrc file:

```
mybackup() {
  dir="/path/to/dir/with/db/files"

  d="$(date +%F)"
  cd "$dir" && for i in *.db; do 
    echo cp "$i" "${i}${d}.db"
  done && cd -
}
```

If everything looks fine remove `echo`.

Syntax: `mybackup`

Comment: Beautiful. I ended up adding `f="${i%.*}"` and then replaced `i` with `f` because i just wan't the filename, not extension. This way resulting file will be `a_2016-04-21.db` instead of `a.db_2016-04-21.db`

Comment: Yes, this is a bug. Good catch!